# google maps formatting text of a marker tooltip on multiple lines

Tags: google-maps-api-3, tooltip, newline, marker

How do I insert a newline into text of a marker tooltip. I am using `\n` which doesn't seem to be working.

See code below:

```js
mark = new google.maps.Marker({          
        map: map,             
        position: center,
        title:inspStates[i].name+ "\n"+"total: "+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ "\n"+ info,
        zIndex:3
});
```

Comment: \n is working in internet explorer but not firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a customized google infoBox in place of the tooltip and it formatted properly
see here: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Comment: This is a bad link.

Comment: I think, this would be that URL: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox

Comment: Internet Archive:
 [http://web.archive.org/web/20160329090524/http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20160329090524/http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

Answer (score 8):

Use single quotes (' ') instead of double quotes (" ")it will work, 
like this code.

```
mark = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map,             
            position: center,
            title:inspStates[i].name+ '\n total: '+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ '\n'+ info,
            zIndex:3
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

When using a Marker, multiline text should be in the `content` not `title`. Also instead of `\n` you must use html's `<br/>`

Comment: worked in the title for me, but you're right about <br/>

Comment: To show a tooltip, I kept it as a `title` and used `\n` without issue.

Answer (score 4):

I use \\n and this seems to work.

Comment: i was using gmplot python library and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FireFox, I don't think there is an easy way.  The problem is explained with brilliant simplicity [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/xil7xCWH8dQ) by one Blake Stephens:

To quote:

> The title that's automatically generated from hovering over a marker
>   is actually the standard HTML title attribute, which works the same
>   way as the alt tag attribute on an image. It's not exactly easy to get
>   multiple lines on one, since browsers decide for themselves when to
>   get the line to wrap (so really long alt texts and titles can be
>   readable, they wrap). I don't believe it's possible to forcibly insert
>   a line break.
>
> However, this does not stop you from circumventing the generic title
>   text altogether and creating your own that's completely stylable. You
>   can attach an even to the marker for the 'mouseover' event and
>   generate a div tag filled with your content that follows the mouse
>   around; removing/destroying/hiding itself when the 'mouseout' event
>   fires. That seems like the most reliable way to me.